# mongoDb stays connected only as long as the user remains logged on the server

Tags: powershell, mongodb

When I connect (ssh@..) to our server and run the mongoDb (mongod --dbPath..), all runs fine.

But as soon as I close the powershell, mongoDb closes too. Why is that?

Could it be related to a user, or is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing your terminal (not PowerShell but the terminal window that PowerShell runs *in*) automatically closes your SSH client that was running inside. The disconnection causes a logout from the SSH server, and in much the same way, the remote processes receive a "hangup" signal and most of them interpret it as indicating that they should exit.

Though daemons such as mongod have a different interpretation (they usually treat it as a "reload" signal instead), so it probably doesn't *directly* lead to mongod exiting, but I have a suspicion it leads to that indirectly.

More than that, however, your server is probably set up to deliberately kill *all* leftover user processes after logout; it's often the default in Linux distributions. It's a reminder that you should be starting services through the system's service manager and not directly from a user's shell.

Most likely your server uses systemd, then all background services should be managed through systemd using `systemctl start mongod` and similar. Services started this way are not attached to your SSH connection.

If you need custom parameters for mongod, those can be added into mongod.service or you can copy the whole thing into e.g. "mongod-custom.service". (Custom .service files can be placed in /etc/systemd/system.)